# Как вставить данные в таблицу БД MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Подскажите как вставить данные в таблицу из запроса:

```
   SELECT af_id, SUM(COALESCE(amount_value,0))*0.1 sum_pair_10
   FROM (SELECT arur.af_id,
   arur.r_w_uid, 
   @row_num :=  CASE WHEN @row_num_val = af_id                THEN @row_num+1
                     WHEN (@row_num_val := af_id) IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                END   pair_flag,
   @lag_r_w_uid :=  CASE WHEN (@row_num_val = af_id) AND @row_num mod 2 = 1 THEN r_w_uid
                         ELSE @lag_r_w_uid
                    END r_w_uid_1     
   FROM arur, u_af, (SELECT @row_num := null, @row_num_val := null, @lag_r_w_uid := null) AS x
   WHERE u_af.id = arur.af_id 
   ORDER BY af_id, r_w_uid) t1  LEFT JOIN orders o ON (o.uid IN (t1.r_w_uid,t1.r_w_uid_1) 
   AND o.status = 'Completed')
   WHERE pair_flag mod 2 = 0
   GROUP BY af_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r_w_uid) >  3
```

Сам запрос выводит всех продавцов, у которых есть определённое количество пар клиентов и показывает 10% от суммы покупок этих клиентов `status` платежей которых `= 'Completed'`. Также этот запрос и таблицы можно посмотреть по ссылке: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=02dbcb8ba5103cd9e2a716449139adce)

После вставки должно получиться так:

```
|ID|          description            |p_id|amount|currency|    date     |status|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |Бонус за: 65,66,68,69,70,71,75,76| 52 |145000|  RUB   |время вставки|  0   |
```

Описание:

`ID` - понятно.

`description` - Бонус за: arur.r_w_uid 4-х пар клиентов с суммы покупок которых показываются проценты в столбце amount.

`p_id` - arur.af_id продавца у которого есть клиенты из столбца description.

`amount` - 10% от суммы покупок 4-х пар клиентов.

`currency` - по-умолчанию RUB.

`date` - время вставки записи.

`status` - по-умолчанию 0.

Описания таблиц задействованных в запросе:

1)

- `orders` - таблица с информацией о платежах.
- `orders.uid` - столбец с внутренним id пользователя.
- `orders.amount_value` - столбец с суммой платежа.
- `orders.status` - столбец со статусом платежа.

2)

- `u_af` - таблица нужна для связи таблицы orders с таблицей arur.

3)

- `arur` - таблица отношений между продавцами и клиентами.
- `arur.af_id` - столбец с id продавца.
- `arur.r_w_uid` - столбец с id клиента.

4)

- `five_pair` - таблица для вставки результатов запроса. Столбцы описаны
  выше.

Пары формируются следующим образом:

Если посмотреть в таблицу arur, то можно увидеть что для, например, af_id = 52 есть несколько записей в столбце r_w_uid. Если взять все записи r_w_uid относящиеся af_id = 52 и поделить их на 2, то получим количество пар. Остаток не включается в пары.

Описание связей таблиц:

- `arur.af_id` = `u_af.id`
- `arur.r_w_uid` = `orders.uid`

Все таблицы и запросы можно увидеть по ссылке: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=02dbcb8ba5103cd9e2a716449139adce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как-то так?

```sql
INSERT INTO five_pair (p_id, amount, description, currency)
SELECT af_id, 
       SUM(COALESCE(amount_value,0))*0.1, 
       CONCAT('Бонус за:', GROUP_CONCAT(r_w_uid)),
       'RUB'
FROM ( SELECT arur.af_id,
              arur.r_w_uid, 
              @row_num := CASE WHEN @row_num_val = af_id                
                               THEN @row_num+1
                               WHEN (@row_num_val := af_id) IS NOT NULL 
                               THEN 1
                               END   pair_flag,
              @lag_r_w_uid :=  CASE WHEN (@row_num_val = af_id) AND @row_num mod 2 = 1 
                                    THEN r_w_uid
                                    ELSE @lag_r_w_uid
                                    END r_w_uid_1     
       FROM arur, 
            u_af, 
            ( SELECT @row_num := null, @row_num_val := null, @lag_r_w_uid := null) AS x
       WHERE u_af.id = arur.af_id 
       ORDER BY af_id, r_w_uid) t1  
LEFT JOIN orders o ON (o.uid IN (t1.r_w_uid,t1.r_w_uid_1) AND o.status = 'Completed' )
WHERE pair_flag mod 2 = 0
GROUP BY af_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT r_w_uid) >  3
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=22d36a23fc379e0021f497be43ef5f5a)

Comment: Cпасибо большое. Всё оказалось намного проще чем я пыталась сделать.

Comment: @ИринаГущина На самом деле для меня загадка - почему Вы, используя MariaDB версии 10.2, возитесь с подзапросами и переменными, хотя можете спокойно использовать оконные функции и CTE...

Comment: Это fiddle MariaDB версии 10.2, а на сервере 5.5.67-MariaDB. Я бы с удовольствием перешла на новую версию, но пока нет возможности, т.к. многие функции перестанут работать.

Comment: Ещё заметила такую проблему в запросе: Есть лишняя запись где p_id = 12. Т.к. в результаты должны попадать только те продавцы 4 пары клиентов которых оплатили заказ (orders.status = 'Completed'), а попадают, видимо, все у кого есть просто 4 пары (arur.r_w_uid). Видимо в самом запросе не правильный отбор. Не подскажете где ошибка?

Comment: @ИринаГущина *Не подскажете где ошибка?* По смыслу сказанного отбор по статусу должен быть в подзапросе, который нумерует записи (который обозван `t1`). Это потребует добавления в условия отбора коррелированного WHERE EXISTS подзапроса (ведь подтверждённых платежей может быть несколько, а умножений нам не надо).

Comment: Значит этот кусок: `LEFT JOIN orders o ON (o.uid IN (t1.r_w_uid,t1.r_w_uid_1) AND o.status = 'Completed' )` не работает?

Comment: @ИринаГущина Ну почему? работает... Вы же считаете сумму платежей `SUM(COALESCE(amount_value,0))*0.1` - именно отсюда данные и берутся, причём только по подтверждённым платежам. Но оно работает ТОЛЬКО на получение данных для суммирования.